# Xamarin Frame color not updating in ListItem

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a ListItem with a Frame inside. In that Frame is a Grid with some labels. The Frame uses Binding to set the color.
When the list is created in this ListItem, using an Observable Collection, the color is set properly to the frame using this Binding method. The problem however is that the Frame does not show any color updates.

I use a NotifyPropertyChanged() to update the colors and this is proven to be working, since I can update the Label colors when I get remove the Frame. So for some reason, the Frame is the big issue here and I have no idea why.

XAML code

```
<ListView SeparatorColor="Transparent" HasUnevenRows="True" x:Name="ListItems">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame BackgroundColor="{Binding NewColor}"> 

                    <Grid>
                        
                        ...
                        
                    </Grid>

                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In the constructor:

```
NewListItems.CollectionChanged += OnItemCollectionChanged;
```

OnItemCollectionChanged

```
private void OnItemCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ChosenItem item in e.NewItems)
    {
        item.NewColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

NotifyPropertyChanged

```
private Color _color;

public Color NewColor
{
    get
    {
        return _color;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != _color)
        {
            _color = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

OnAppearing

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    ListItems.ItemsSource = NewListItems;
}
```

So this should update the background color of the Frame, or I'm missing something here. I hope anyone knows the solution.

Comment: As a sanity check, if you start with xaml `<Frame BackgroundColor="Blue">`, does it appear blue?

Comment: Similarly, if in ChosenColor constructor, you do `NewColor = Color.Blue;`, does the binding to Frame work then? These two tests are to be 100% sure there isn't some different problem.

Comment: With the xaml option: yes it turns blue. For the constructor option: sorry but I'm not sure which constructor you mean.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Extra comment: the Binding on its own does work (since the color is properly assigned to the Frame when I open the list). The issue is the update of the Frame color: when the color is updated, the Frame keeps its first assigned color.

Comment: *"the Binding on its own does work "* - good, that is what I was verifying. Sounds like a xamarin bug with updating background color of Frame. You can add a new issue at `github xamarin forms issues`, but its not likely to get fixed. Try to work-around by setting NewColor before adding items to collection. Sometimes, a work-around is to set ItemsSource = null, then set it back to the collection.

Comment: This work-around is so simple and it actually works :P. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like there is already a bug report on this with the current status of We've moved this issue to the Backlog milestone. This means that it is not going to be worked on for the coming release. We will reassess the backlog following the current release and consider this item at that time. " 
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12044#issue-1493212869

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ToolmakerSteve.

There is a simple work-around for this issue by simply setting the listitems first to null and then load it again.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    ListItems.ItemsSource = null;
    ListItems.ItemsSource = NewListItems;
}
```

A solid solution is yet to be found, but this works as well.

Comment: Note: If this ever doesn't do the trick, then delay the second line until after xamarin UI has reached a "quiet state" (finished the work it was doing). Like this: `ListItems.ItemsSource = null;` `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { ListItems.ItemsSource = NewListItems 
 });`  Downside: that delay displays page twice, first time with empty list. Maui will be tweaked until it doesn't need hacks like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Model** using `MVVM` and then separately assign the `Frame Color` of each item in the `ListView`. Here's the code snippet for your reference:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {

        private Color _color;

        public Color NewColor
        {
            get => _color;
            set
            {
                _color = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_color));
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>
            {
                new MyItem{NewColor = Color.Blue, NewText="This is a test1"},
                new MyItem{NewColor = Color.Red,  NewText="This is a test2"},
                new MyItem{NewColor = Color.Green,NewText="This is a test3"}

            };
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**Xaml:**

```
<ListView x:Name="ListItems" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"> 
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <ViewCell>
                     <Frame BackgroundColor="{Binding NewColor}">
                         <StackLayout>
                             <Label Text="{Binding NewText}" FontSize="Body"/>
                         </StackLayout>
                           
                            
                      </Frame>
                  </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            
 </ListView>
```

Comment: But does that allow me to update colors while using the app?

Comment: You are not providing your ViewModel code. I think you should notify the value of 'NewColor' if it is changed. Add it to your set method should get it fixed.